# Intercepting queried params in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Users are required to confirm their account before they can fully sign in. When they register, they get sent an email with a link like below:

```
somewebsite.com/confirmations?confirmation_token=rpSLUPpsHsYxkvYkXY_s
```

In my vue router I have tried variations on the following route:

```js
{ path: "confirmations", component: Component }

// Or

{ path: "confirmations?", component: Component }

// Or

{ path: "confirmations?confirmation_token=:id", component: Component }
```

While `/confirmations` works with a general page, any attempt to go to a URL with a confirmation token does not work.

Ideally, the user would directed to the confirmations page that will let the user know if the confirmation was valid or not.

Comment: On the confirmation page, you need to use `route.query` or `this.$route.query` to get the query parameters.

Comment: @Gabe I'm not trying to get the query parameters on the page at the moment, I'm trying to get the router to go to an existing page.

Comment: I am sorry, but than I don’t understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are not considered part of a route's path.  Path should also always start with `/`.  You should define your route as such:

```js
{ path: "/confirmations", component: Component }
```

The URL `/confirmations?confirmation_token=rpSLUPpsHsYxkvYkXY_s` should still take you to `Component`, and everything after `?` in the URL will be accessible on the route's `query` property.

```js
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
const query = route.query // { "confirmation_token": "rpSLUPpsHsYxkvYkXY_s" }
</script>
```

Query params are nothing you need to specify in your routes file.